# Postgres: Why would query planner choose Nested Loop Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two huge tables which I want to join

```
live_inventory_calculation: 8.1M records
demand: 3M records
```

Query planner is using **NestledLoop Join**, which obviously is taking more than a minute. There is already an index on the joining columns. Disabling the nested loop with

```
SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = False;
```

Forces the planner to use **Hash Join** whic takes only *12 seconds*.

Here is the query

```sql
SELECT 
live_inventory_calculation.csku_id,
live_inventory_calculation.dc_code,
live_inventory_calculation.date,
count(*)
FROM live_inventory_calculation
         INNER JOIN demand ON
            live_inventory_calculation.csku_id = demand.sku_id
        AND live_inventory_calculation.dc_code = demand.dc_code
        AND live_inventory_calculation.date = demand.date
GROUP BY live_inventory_calculation.csku_id, live_inventory_calculation.dc_code,
         live_inventory_calculation.production_week;
```

This is the case with every join with `live_inventory_calculation` table. I have refreshed the stats so query planner has the correct statistics.

Here is the plan for both

[Hash Join](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/1ggbb31f19e1496c)

[NestedLoop Join](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/6faae2600d3e82dd)

### **Questions**

1. Since both the tables are huge, why would query planner choose nested loop join?
2. How can I make query planner to choose hashjoin, without using flags?

Comment: Sorry I changed the query to remove the noise. I fixed it.

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? In plain text, as an update to your question

Comment: First I'd vacuum and analyze both tables and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Your plan shows it only taking 30 seconds for the nested loop.  Is that due to caching/repeated execution?

Comment: One possibility is that it thinks memoize will be much more effective than it actually is.  the only way I know of to test this is to `set enable_memoize TO off` (but enable_nestloop to on) and look at the resulting plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Since both the tables are huge, why would query planner choose nested loop join?

The query planner is choosing the `nested loop` because the two sides of the join are one-large (3M rows), one-supersmall (0 rows).  That would logically be the best way to join, because it takes extra time to sort-and-merge (Merge Join) or to hash-and-search (Hash Join).

Without knowing what data lives in the `live_inventory_calculation` table, I suppose based on your objections that there should be a lot of matching rows, not zero.  It seems that the memoize cache does not have the required data (`Misses: 3009118`) so it needs to go to disk (or elsewhere) to retrieve the actual data.

When you set `enable_nestedloop = off`, it decides that joining with the `memoize` cache is too expensive, so it chooses the next best option, which is the Hash Join - this ends up being quick (but if the memoize cache was better, the original plan would probably faster).

2. How can I make query planner to choose hashjoin, without using flags?

It would be good to know which version of Postgres you're working with -- there have been [many bug fixes related to memoize](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=11&to=16&keywords=memoize) in the past several years.

Comment: I am using 15.3. Seems like there has been some fix in Verion 16. I will try it now :D

Comment: So I upgraded to 15.4 from 15.3. 16 was not available in RDS at that time. And it worked. Its not using nested join anymore.